# css drop down z-index issue in ie7 only

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, internet-explorer-7, z-index

For some reason the z-index is not working properly in ie7 only.  If I remove position:fixed from #header it works fine, however, as this menu is to be fixed at the top of the page this is needed.  The drop down shows, but only over the bottom border and nothing below that.  Can't figure this one out.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GVUXw/)

```
<!-- start fixed header container -->
<div id="header_container">
    <!-- start header -->
    <div id="header">
        <!-- start container -->
        <nav>
            <div class="container">
                <div id="logo">logo here</div>
                <div id="top_menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="/#">Features</a>
                            <div class="drop">
                                <div>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li class="title"><a href="/#1">heading with link</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="/#1">testing 1</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="/#2">testing 2</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="/#3">testing 3</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li class="title"><a href="/#1">and another heading</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="/#1">testing 1</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="/#2">testing 2</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="/#3">testing 3</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div class="extra">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li class="title">heading with NO link</li>
                                        <li><a href="/#4">testing 4</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="/#5">testing 5</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="/#6">testing 6</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li class="title">plain info description goes as far as I want <br />with no link blah blah blah blah blah</li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="/#">Download</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/#">Purchase</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/#">Support</a>
                            <div class="drop">
                                <div>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li class="title">How can we help you?</li>
                                        <li><a href="/#1">FAQs</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="/#2">How To Guides</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="/#3">Online Documentation</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="/#3">Contact Us</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="/#">Account Login</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <!-- end container -->
        <div class="header_shadow"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- end header -->
</div>
<!-- end header container -->



#header_container{
width:100%;
height:52px;
}

#header{
width:100%;
height:50px;
position:fixed;
border-bottom:2px #3c9ac4 solid;
background: #00457b;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#1e70b2), to(#00457b)); 
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #1e70b2, #00457b); 
background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #1e70b2, #00457b); 
background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #1e70b2, #00457b); 
background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #1e70b2, #00457b); 
background-image:         linear-gradient(top, #1e70b2, #00457b);
 }

.ie8 #header, .ie9 #header{
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1e70b2', endColorstr='#00457b',GradientType=0 ) ;
}

.header_shadow{
width:100%;
height:10px;
position:absolute;
z-index:900;
display:none;
left:0;
top:52px;
background:url(/images/header_shadow.png) repeat-x;
 }


 /* Top Menu
 ================================================== */

#logo{
width:200px;
float:left;
}

/*menu container centered*/
#top_menu{
width:760px;
float:left;
}

/*entire menu ul*/
#top_menu ul{
position:relative;
z-index:1000;
margin:0;
float:right;
height:50px;
line-height:50px;
}

/*top link container*/
#top_menu ul li{
display:block;
float:left;
}

/*top link*/
#top_menu ul li a{
display:block;
color:#f1f1f1;
text-decoration:none;
padding:0 20px;
font-size:14px;
}

/*top link hover*/
#top_menu ul li:hover > a{      
color: #f1f1f1;
background:#555555;
}


/*show dropdown and position under tab*/
#top_menu ul li:hover > .drop{
display:block;
top:auto;
}

/*drop down container*/
#top_menu ul li .drop{
position:absolute;
z-index:1000;
display:none;
padding:15px 0 0 0;
-moz-border-radius:0 0 8px 8px;
-webkit-border-radius:0 0 8px 8px;
border-radius:0 0 8px 8px;

background:#555555;
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#555555), to(#202020)); 
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #555555, #202020); 
background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, #555555, #202020); 
background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, #555555, #202020); 
background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, #555555, #202020); 
background-image:         linear-gradient(top, #555555, #202020);
font-size:13px;
}

.ie8 #top_menu ul li .drop{
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#555555', endColorstr='#202020',GradientType=0 ) ;
}

.ie9 #top_menu ul li .drop{
background-image:url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIHZpZXdCb3g9IjAgMCAxIDEiIHByZXNlcnZlQXNwZWN0UmF0aW89Im5vbmUiPgo8bGluZWFyR3JhZGllbnQgaWQ9Imc1ODIiIGdyYWRpZW50VW5pdHM9InVzZXJTcGFjZU9uVXNlIiB4MT0iMCUiIHkxPSIwJSIgeDI9IjAlIiB5Mj0iMTAwJSI+CjxzdG9wIHN0b3AtY29sb3I9IiM1NTU1NTUiIG9mZnNldD0iMCIvPjxzdG9wIHN0b3AtY29sb3I9IiMyMDIwMjAiIG9mZnNldD0iMSIvPgo8L2xpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50Pgo8cmVjdCB4PSIwIiB5PSIwIiB3aWR0aD0iMSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxIiBmaWxsPSJ1cmwoI2c1ODIpIiAvPgo8L3N2Zz4=);
}

/*drop down div*/
#top_menu ul li .drop div{
float:left;
padding:0 30px 0 10px;
line-height:normal;
}

/*drop down div floated left*/
#top_menu ul li .drop div.extra{
/*border-left:1px #eeeeee solid;*/
}

#top_menu ul li .drop div .title, #top_menu ul li .drop div .title a{
padding:0 0 4px 0;
border:none;
color:#f1f1f1;
font-size:13px;
}

#top_menu ul li .drop div .title a:hover{
text-decoration:underline;
}

#top_menu ul li .drop div ul{
width:auto;
height:auto;
float:none;
background:none;
border:none;
margin:0 0 15px 0;
}

#top_menu ul li .drop div ul li{
float:none;
padding:1px 0 1px 0;
line-height:normal;
}

#top_menu ul li .drop div ul li:hover a{
background:none;
}

#top_menu ul li .drop div ul li a{
display:inline;
padding:0;
border:none;
color:#6cc5d8;
font-size:13px;
}

#top_menu ul li .drop div ul li a:hover{
text-decoration:underline;
}
```

Comment: Strange. Working fine in IE7 for me. Do you have a valid doctype declared on your page?

Comment: Just using html5 - <!DOCTYPE html> - just to make sure I commented out everything except the menu on my page... keeping the needed stuff there of course, but removing the rest of the page contents... still have the same issue.  If it makes a difference I am using IE9 and just using dev tools to show in IE7 which I assume most people do as well.  If I remove the position:fixed as noted above the problem goes away, but then again it is not fixed anymore either.

Comment: I should note - the actual container everything is in has a two pixel border on the bottom.  The drop down 'shows' but only covering that 2 pixel height.  Anything below it is not shown.  This is not the same as just the regular top level hover state as it would not cover the border.  Very strange.  At some point something happened because I had this all working at one point fine... probably before I made it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by adding yet another wrapper wound the header and making it position fixed.  So it goes as container the width/height (to keep spacing of the rest of the page correct), container width/height fixed, then header container with logo/drop-down within that.  Solves the problem in ie7 and every other browser worked fine before.